# Magento 2.1 admin panel login not working after installation

Tags: xampp, magento2

I know this question were asked multiple times on stackoverflow, but I could not find any proper solution.
I am using Magento 2.1.7. After successfully installing Magento, I clicked on "Launch Magento Admin", They told me to enter username and password. But the problem is that I find Admin Panel Login crashed, as shown below: 
[Crashes Magento Login Admin PAnel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6j2a.png)

**EDIT2: This is what i got when you to me to run this command:php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy  ** [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yd5Sz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check that you have the .htaccess file in the pub/static directory:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1.4/pub/static/.htaccess

This will add the rewrite for version URLS.

Versions are for cache busting static assets, you can read about cachebusting here: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Hope this helps

Comment: hello sir,  i am sorry i didn't get you. Can you please explain me in detail?

Comment: delete cache and generation folder inside var in your Magento root folder. Then run the command bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: it says: fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 is exhausted

Comment: @HeebahSaleem Restarted appache?

Comment: try changing to 1024M

Comment: Inspect the browser console. It will show if any error. pls check

Comment: @HeebahSaleem Updated answer

Comment: Sir, please see EDIT 2. And please let me know, what to do after this?

Comment: it worked. thank you sir. No errors in console. When i ran that command. :)